# Wagtail editor deletes content

Tags: wagtail

An intern created a Wagtail site at our company. I am in charge to fill a page with our Terms And Conditions. This is hard because Wagtail is deleting or skipping content. There is a pattern to this behavior. Perhaps it gets triggered by the specific structure this content has. For now, being new to Wagtail, it does not feel very trustworthy if Wagtail randomly deletes content. Up to the pattern: There are articles that have the following structure:

```
A5.3 It's not allowed to use our Services for:

a. bla;
b. foo;
c. foo cookie jar;

A5.4 Regarding article
```

The a-c parts always get deleted by Wagtail. Sometimes it holds it quite some time but if I make a few edits, those a-c parts get erased.

Has anyone a clue why Wagtail is doing this?

Kind regards and thank you for helping me out.

Bram

Comment: Hi, without more information it is hard to know what is happening but this could be a bug. Would you be able to raise this as a bug? https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/new/choose -> it would be good to have some screenshots and if possible some example code (maybe from the intern). Sorry to hear you are having issues but more information will be needed to give you help and this sounds like it would be best suited as a bug on the Wagtail repo.

Comment: I've been using Wagtail for 4 years now and never seen this type of behavior.  It sounds like something going on with the way the intern developed the site.  Can you please provide more code references, specifically the model for the page that generates this content and the HTML template for the page?